# I need CSS selector to select elements that contain a given text

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Line:

```
<div class="btn btn-second-in-pair-not-desired btn-tall">Clear search</div>
<div class="btn btn-second-in-pair-not-desired btn-tall">Raw Search</div>
<div class="btn btn-second-in-pair-not-desired btn-tall">Basic Search</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary-stand-alone btn-tall search-btn">Search</div>
```

Here is what i have tried so far - 
".btn:contains('Clear search')" but selenium is not able to catch it

Comment: There is no CSS selector based on raw text.

Comment: Can you try css=div.btn:contains('Clear search'). ref: https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

Comment: please provide the parent source in which these div lie then only you will get accurate css selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS Selector doesn't support `:contains()` anymore. You have to use XPath `"//div[text()='Clear search']"`.

Comment: Thanks @Buaban. to keep the things simple, i have decided to use xpath.

Comment: @ user3121891 i am glad that you have decided to go with xpath which is working for you but please change this question as question and answer do not match as you have explicitly said you need css selector

Answer (score 2):

User below css code:

```
css=div:contains('Clear search')
```

More details click on link: [SauceLab](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

If your using Selenium, it also accepts XPATH strings, which can sometimes be more flexible than CSS Selectors in some instances. Because I'm super lazy as well, I find it quite handy that you can right click a tag in the Elements view of DevTools and "Copy > Copy XPath"

```
webDriver.findElement(
  By.xpath(
    "//div[text()='Clear search']"
  )
).click();
```

Comment: This worked and i think to be on the safe side i better use xpath. Thanks a a lot @Kraig

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change the class depending on the content ?

```
<?php 
$content = $your_content_from_database;
$arr_content = explode(" ", $content);
$first = $arr_content[0];
echo '<div class="btn btn-second-in-pair-not-desired btn-tall clear" data-content="'.$first.'">'. $content. '</div>' ; ?>
```

and the CSS

```
[data-content="Clear"]{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi on the basis of the source provided by you in the question you can use css selector as below to identify the elements

```
// take everything inside the list for div with same class
List<WebElement> mycsselements =  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-second-in-pair-not-desired.btn-tall"));
System.out.println("Size of the div elements with same class name : " + mycsselements.size());
// printing value one by one 
System.out.println("First value is "  + mycsselements.get(0).getText());
System.out.println("Second value is " + mycsselements.get(1).getText());
System.out.println("Third value is "  + mycsselements.get(2).getText());

// and for the last one do it like below

System.out.println("Last value is " + driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary-stand-alone.btn-tall.search-btn")).getText());
```

and the output is :

```
Size of the div elements with same class name : 3
First value is Clear search
Second value is Raw Search
Third value is Basic Search
Last value is Search
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score -1):

I don't think css supports searching by content of the html element.

Why not try:

```
<div class="btn btn-second-in-pair-not-desired btn-tall clear">Clear search</div>
<div class="btn btn-second-in-pair-not-desired btn-tall raw">Raw Search</div>
<div class="btn btn-second-in-pair-not-desired btn-tall basic">Basic Search</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary-stand-alone btn-tall search-btn">Search</div>
```

And then selecting via:

```
.btn{
  color:red;
}

.clear, .raw, .basic, .search-btn{
  color:blue;
}
```

Or you could always try using ids

```
<div id="search">Search</div>
```

select:

```
#search{
 ...
}
```